# Internationalization react application. How extract messages?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, babeljs

I have an application by using typescript, babel, react and I want to add Internationalization to my app.
How to extract my en.json to another locales for example.

I have translations in my ./src/translations

en.json

```
{
  "page.login.title: "Login",
  "page.login.link.forgot.passowrd: "Forgot password"
}
```

ru.json

```
{
  "page.login.title: "Страница входа",
}
```

ua.json

```
{
 "page.login.link.forgot.passowrd: "Забув пароль"
}
```

How I can get files in my folder ./src/translations as below after extract

en.json

```
{
  "page.login.title: "Login",
  "page.login.link.forgot.passowrd: "Forgot password"
}
```

ru.json

```
{
  "page.login.title: "Страница входа",
  "page.login.link.forgot.passowrd: "Forgot password"
}
```

ua.json

```
{
 "page.login.title: "Login",
 "page.login.link.forgot.passowrd: "Забув пароль"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written script on nodejs

```
const fs = require('fs');

const MAIN_LANGUAGE = './src/translations/en.json';
const LANG_DIR = './src/translations/';

const mainLocale = JSON.parse(
  fs.readFileSync(MAIN_LANGUAGE, 'utf8', error => {
    if (error) throw error;
  })
);

fs.readdirSync(LANG_DIR).forEach(file => {
  const currentLocale = JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync(`${LANG_DIR}/${file}`, 'utf8', error => {
      if (error) throw error;
    })
  );

  const updatedCurrentLocale = JSON.stringify(
    { ...mainLocale, ...currentLocale },
    null,
    2
  );

  fs.writeFileSync(
    `${LANG_DIR}/${file}`,
    updatedCurrentLocale,
    'utf8',
    error => {
      if (error) throw error;
    }
  );

  console.log(`READY LOCALE: ${file}`);
});
```